# Friend ostream operator << wont acces private fields

Tags: private, operator-keyword, friend, ostream

It just wont acces private fields

```
.hpp:
private:
    std::string model;

public:
    Piekarnik &operator << (const Ciasto &ciasto);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Ciasto &ciasto);


.cpp:
Piekarnik &Piekarnik::operator<<(const Ciasto &ciasto)
{
    append(ciasto);
    return *this;
}
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Piekarnik &piekarnik) // dwuargumentowy;
{
      os<<"Piekarnik (model: "<<piekarnik.model<<", temperatura: " << piekarnik.obecnyProgram.temperatura <<", pieczenie: " << EnumToString(piekarnik.obecnyProgram.pieczenie) << ", wlozone ciasto: " << EnumToString(piekarnik.wlozoneCiasto.rodzaj);
      return os<<")";
}
```

> error: 'std::string Piekarnik::model' is private

Comment: Check your declaration and definition signature, it's not matched. Here is the declared `friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Ciasto &ciasto);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your friend declaration to

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Piekarnik&);
```

Comment: worked! 
just one more class and same problem, gonna try to do it by myself

Comment: error: 'unsigned int Program::temperatura' is private|

its in another class Program, what should I type there to make it work perfectly?

Comment: Use a getter in class `Program` or put the same friend declaration to class `Program` or just mark it public member

Comment: same friend declaration: Piekarnik not defined (no doubts)
alright, thanks

Comment: Forward declaration for class `Piekarnik`